# How does offline/persistent access with Flutter/Firebase/Google Identity work?

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-functions, google-signin, google-identity

I have poured through documentation and countless attempts for weeks and months now to try and connect the dots in the Authentication and Authorization process for a Flutter application requiring Google Sign In.

What I'm trying to implement is a tool that will make changes to one of the user's YouTube videos (pre-specified by the user) every day at a specific time. I know that in order to achieve this I need to authenticate the user in the app using google Sign in before gaining authorization from the user to make changes on their behalf to their YouTube channel. As I'll be making changes without their presence, I will need to request offline access and of course whatever additional scopes are required.

I know this was (at least at some stage) a challenge with Android/iOS apps made though Flutter, so I'm happy to proceed and just attempt this through a Flutter web app for now, but I'm confused around exactly what the steps to follow are. My understanding was that I had to utilize maybe the beforeUserCreated blocking Function to complete the authorization piece, to grab the refresh token and securely save that to Firestore for future use when needed.

However, last night I was using the GoogleAuthProvider from the firebase_auth package, and I was able to request offline access and the scopes I needed through here, etc. and also noticed I could get the refresh token from here too. Is this the refresh token I need to refresh the access token for the users google account once it expires or is this a refresh token simply for Firebase Auth? I'm not certain. To clarify, I believe I have everything set up correctly in Google Cloud for the oAuth key, client id, redirect url's, etc.

Any help here to clarify the above would be great, as the next step I need to understand is what I need to do to use the refresh token to refresh the access token once it has expired. I feel there is very little clarity and a lot of confusion in the documentation about what exactly the processes are here.

Thank you in advance for any guidance here and apologies for the wall of text.